# Chaining lambda functions vs. Making program async

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda, python-asyncio

I have an AWS Lambda function written in python that is starting to get a bit too big. It often runs over the AWS Lambda limit of 15 minutes.

The function is responsible for making loads of API calls, and unfortunately I have not taken the time to make them all async yet.

The workflow for the function looks something roughly like this:

1. Receive data for xxx clients (1 api call)
2. Place API call for each client and wait for response (xxx api calls)
3. Based on #2 API call response, place yet another API call for each client and wait for response (xxx api calls)
4. Store response from #3 in DynamoDB (xxx DB updates)

Initially my plan was to just keep everything in 1 lambda function, and modify my code such that all API calls run async, and to do one big dynamoDB batch update at the end.

However, it occurs to me that theoretically this function could still grow too large in the future, if we start needing to run it for enormous numbers of clients. Additionally, in my opinion, managing all those python async calls can be a bit cumbersome in specific situations.

My second approach, is to chain together lambda functions. That is, create a second lambda function, let's name it "order_for_single_client", which perform steps #2-4 for just one client.

The top level lambda function will gather data on all clients, and for each one, make a separate lambda call to "order_for_single_client". So, if we need to order for 500 clients, the top level function will just make 500 separate lambda calls. Naturally, all the async behavior should take care of itself on the end of AWS since it will run the lambda functions in parallel. (with the exception of the batch dynamoDB update we wanted, but we can worry about that later).

1. What is the preferred way of handling this situation from an architecture perspective? Splitting things up into a lambda chain, or trying to speed things up using async inside a single lambda function?
2. If we were to implement the lambda chain, will it be more or less expensive to run at scale compared to the single function async approach?
3. Is there a third design solution to this problem that I have not considered? (Apart from spinning up an EC2 instance, which I would prefer not to do).

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect case for [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/).

Comment: Thanks!

Are there any gotchya's I should watch out for, specifically with regards to invocation limits? If you look at AWS Lambda limits:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

It limits by the following:
10 x concurrent executions limit (synchronous – all sources)
10 x concurrent executions limit (asynchronous – non-AWS sources)
Unlimited (asynchronous – AWS service sources)

Do step functions count as an "AWS service source" in this case?

Comment: All those limits are soft limits, but yes, these would count toward them. If you are going to go over those limits you can ask for an increase. If you’re just going to burst over the limits you’ll probably be fine. Retry logic should handle any throttling you’d see.